# Initialize method not invoking

Tags: java, javafx, initialization, gluon

I want to add a spinner in my javafx project including maxmimum(1) and minimum(5).

The problem is that the initialize method is not invoking.
When does the initialize should be invoked? Why doesn't it?

This is the App.java code:

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.Parent;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class AverageApp extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception {
        Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("FXMLDocument.fxml"));

        Scene scene = new Scene(root);

        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

}
```

This is my FXMLController.java Code

```
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.ResourceBundle;
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.fxml.Initializable;
import javafx.scene.control.Spinner;
import javafx.scene.control.SpinnerValueFactory;

import javafx.scene.input.*;

public class FXMLDocumentController implements Initializable{

    @FXML private Spinner spi;

    @Override
    public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle rb) {
        System.out.println("HI");
        this.spi.setValueFactory(new SpinnerValueFactory.IntegerSpinnerValueFactory(1, 5));
    }

}
```

And This is my FXMLDocument.fxml code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.scene.web.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.image.*?>
<?import java.lang.*?>
<?import java.util.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.*?>

<AnchorPane maxHeight="-Infinity" maxWidth="-Infinity" minHeight="-Infinity" minWidth="-Infinity" prefHeight="714.0" prefWidth="584.0" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8.0.40" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1">
   <children>
      <AnchorPane layoutX="108.0" layoutY="30.0">
         <children>
            <Spinner fx:id="spi" />
         </children>
      </AnchorPane>
      <Label layoutX="278.0" layoutY="34.0" text="تعداد واحد :" />
      <Label layoutX="510.0" layoutY="34.0" text="نام درس :" />
      <TextField alignment="CENTER" layoutX="380.0" layoutY="30.0" nodeOrientation="LEFT_TO_RIGHT" prefHeight="25.0" prefWidth="120.0" />
      <Button layoutX="34.0" layoutY="98.0" mnemonicParsing="false" text="اضافه کردن" />
      <Label layoutX="520.0" layoutY="123.0" text="Label" />
      <Label layoutX="520.0" layoutY="162.0" text="Label" />
   </children>
</AnchorPane>
```

Comment: You need to use the `fx:controller` attribute in your fxml.

Comment: @fabian thanks for the answer. but where do I need add this attribute?

Comment: Take a look at the examples here: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/javafx/fxml/doc-files/introduction_to_fxml.html#controllers

Comment: Thank you @fabian I'm amazingly surprised!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on @fabian, your `FXML` is missing something like:

```
fx:controller="yourpackagename.FXMLDocumentController ">
```

It should be a part of your root node:

```
<AnchorPane maxHeight="-Infinity" maxWidth="-Infinity" minHeight="-Infinity" minWidth="-Infinity" prefHeight="714.0" prefWidth="584.0" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8.0.40" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="yourpackagename.FXMLDocumentController ">
```